# melting to long format

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame('Dev' = 1:12,
                 'GWP' = seq(10,120,10),
                 '2012' = 1:12,
                 'Inc' = seq(10,120,10),
                 'GWP2' = c(seq(10,100,10),NA,NA),
                 '2013'= 1:12,
                 'Inc2' = c(seq(10,100,10),NA,NA),
                 'GWP3' = c(seq(10,80,10),NA,NA,NA,NA),
                 '2014'= 1:12,
                 'Inc3' = c(seq(10,80,10),NA,NA,NA,NA))

head(df)

result_df <- data.frame('Dev' = rep(1:12,3),
                        'GWP' = c(seq(10,120,10),
                                  c(seq(10,100,10),NA,NA),
                                  c(seq(10,80,10),NA,NA,NA,NA)),
                        'YEAR' = c(rep(2012,12),
                                   rep(2013,12),
                                   rep(2014,12)),
                        'Inc' = c(seq(10,120,10),
                                  c(seq(10,100,10),NA,NA),
                                  c(seq(10,80,10),NA,NA,NA,NA))) 
head(result_df)
```

The above is my data structure.

I'm trying to make the df to look like result_df. I'm assuming using the library reshape2 somehow would do the trick but I'm having troubles getting it to come out as expected:

```
x <- melt(df,id=c("Dev"))

x$value <- ifelse(x$variable == 'X2012',2012,
                  ifelse(x$variable == 'X2013',2013,
                         ifelse(x$variable == 'X2014',2014,x$value)))


x$variable <- ifelse(x$variable %in% c('GWP','GWP2','GWP3'),'GWP',
                     ifelse(x$variable %in% c('Inc','Inc2','Inc3'), 'Inc',
                            ifelse(x$variable %in% c('X2012','X2013','X2014'),"Year",
                                   x$variable)))
```

The problem is that the "year" column in my actual data can go for 20-30 years and I want to avoid using multiple ifelse statements to map them up. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data needs some pre-processing before getting the expected output. Using `tidyverse` one possible way is

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
   gather(key, value, -Dev) %>%
   mutate(col = case_when(str_detect(key, "^GWP") ~ "GWP", 
                           str_detect(key, "^X") ~ "Year", 
                           str_detect(key, "^Inc") ~ "Inc"), 
          value = ifelse(col == "Year", sub("^X", "", key), value)) %>%
   select(-key) %>%
   group_by(col) %>%
   mutate(Dev1 = row_number()) %>%
   spread(col, value) %>% 
   select(-Dev1)

# A tibble: 36 x 4
#     Dev GWP   Inc   Year 
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 10    10    2012 
# 2     1 10    10    2013 
# 3     1 10    10    2014 
# 4     2 20    20    2012 
# 5     2 20    20    2013 
# 6     2 20    20    2014 
# 7     3 30    30    2012 
# 8     3 30    30    2013 
# 9     3 30    30    2014 
#10     4 40    40    2012 
# … with 26 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had one question, why do you need to group_by(col) and the Dev1 column? And also why do you need them in that order? If you create Dev1 first it doesn't work

Comment: @user33484 using `spread` we are trying to convert the data into wide format. To do that we need a common identifier across all the values which would decide in which row each value should be placed, that is the reason we need `Dev1`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this works for the first part:

```
apply(matrix(c(2012:2014)), 1, function(y) x$value[x$variable == paste("X", y, sep = "")] <<- y )
```

1. create a 1 dim matrix to iterate over using apply.
2. create a function to replace the values found through masking.
3. **Note** the use of the `<<-`, it assigns the respective values to the `x` scoped one level above that of the function defined in the `apply`.
4. Note it applies the function to the variable `x` and returns the values used in the replacement.

For the second part:

```
x$variable[x$variable %in% c('GWP', 'GWP2', 'GWP3')] <- "GWP"

x$variable[x$variable %in% c('Inc', 'Inc2', 'Inc3')] <- "Inc"
```

Since the variable column is type `factor` and `Year` is not a `level`:

```
x <- transform(x, variable = as.character(variable))

x$variable[x$variable %in% c('X2012', 'X2013', 'X2014')] <- "Year"

x <- transform(x, variable = as.factor(variable))
```